# Load a two texture for a single image at a regular interval of time - GLkit openglES

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, opengl-es, glkit

I used the below code to load the texture on a object.

```
- (void)ldText:(UIImage *)Image
{
    glGenTextures(1, &texture);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

    CGImageRef cgImage = Image.CGImage;
    float Width = CGImageGetWidth(cgImage);
    float Height = CGImageGetHeight(cgImage);
    CFDataRef data = CGDataProviderCopyData(CGImageGetDataProvider(cgImage));

    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, Width, Height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, CFDataGetBytePtr(data));
}
```

The texture is getting mapped properly.

I need to load two textures now. And the textures should get changed at regular interval of time. Is it possible? Can Some one guide me how to proceed from here?

****Update:***
I loaded another texture with Image2, with the function ldText2. And updating it in each "update view". Now I get two textures on the same object and getting changed whenever the "update" function is called. I interchange the texture1 and texture2 each time when the "Update" function is called.
But the problem is time interval! I want it to happen slow. How to set a time interval for this?*

Comment: Such as using this method of NSObject?

- (void)performSelector:(SEL)aSelector withObject:(id)anArgument afterDelay:(NSTimeInterval)delay;

Answer (score 0):

By default GLKViewController provides you with an animation loop which calls update based on the `preferredFramesPerSecond` property.  (The rate actually used is in the `framesPerSecond` property).

You could gain some control by setting the preferred rate, but you are more likely to want to turn off the animation loop if you want the display to remain static for more than a fraction of a second.  To do this, set the `paused` property to **YES**, and override `resumeOnDidBecomeActive` to return **NO**.  You will then need to make sure `display` gets called on the view at the appropriate times, either by doing so explicitly or by making sure the `enableSetNeedsDisplay` property on the view is set to **YES**, and invalidating the view.

If you want to keep the animation loop active for other reasons, then Matic Oblak's suggestion of using a delayed selector execution can be applied to either change the texture, or to set a flag to trigger the update method to change the texture.