# Rotate an image and get back to its original position - opengles glkit

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, opengl-es, glkit

I need to rotate an image in opengles GLkit and get it back to its original position in GLkit.

```
rotation += 5;
_modelViewMatrix = GLKMatrix4Rotate( _modelViewMatrix, GLKMathDegreesToRadians(5), 1, 0, 0);
_modelViewMatrix = GLKMatrix4Rotate( _modelViewMatrix, GLKMathDegreesToRadians(rotation), 1,0,0);
```

I need to move it in x axis for certain amount and getting back to its original position from where it started. How should i do it?

Comment: think we need a bit more of an explanation here, its a little ambiguous. when you say moving in x axis are you translating? surely if you rotate back the amount you rotated forward it will return you to your original position

Comment: @Fonix ya I tried moving GLKMathDegreesToRadians(-5)radians in the next "update" but the object rotates full circle. I dont na what is wrong with this.

Comment: maybe keep a separate matrix that you do all your rotations on, then multiply it with your modelViewMatrix each update instead of rotating your actual modelViewMatrix.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more in detail as an answer!

Comment: @Fonix And also can you please comment on this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15407033/load-a-two-texture-for-a-single-image-at-a-regular-interval-of-time-glkit-open